# Opera userscript is loading too often

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera, userscripts

I made user script. I test this on Opera 11.62. I have a code:

```
(
    function() {
        var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
        var newScript = document.createElement('script');
        newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        newScript.id = 'myjQuery';
        newScript.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
        headID.appendChild(newScript);

        newScript.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
            jQuery (
                function($) {
                    alert('loaded');
                }
            );          
        },false);

        newScript.removeEventListener('load');
    }
)();
```

My problem is that it's showing the alert message too many times,
each time with different domain in the alert title.

I know it's Facebook's and advertisement windows' fault.
Can I load a userscript after all scripts on a site are loaded?

Answer (score 5):

It seems the problem is that Opera is firing the script for each iframe.  Adding this code to the top of your script should clear that up:

```
if (window.top != window.self)  //-- Don't run on frames or iframes.
    return;
```

Also, it's not clear that you are setting the script's targets the way Opera expects.

Unless you are [running the script in Greasemonkey mode](http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/examples/#greasemonkey), be sure your code is wrapped by domain/URL sensing like so:

```
if (location.hostname.indexOf('example.com') != -1) {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

See ["Loading scripts" in the Opera manual](http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/examples/#loadingscripts).

Comment: It's very helpfull, thanks :)
 
If i will have problem with this script, i wrote here.

Comment: Hi, just a small tip on using Stackoverflow: please mark the above answer as "accepted". This helps us know that the question is answered.